# Driving On Utah Salt Flats

Tags: usa, driving, automobiles, off-road, utah

Are you able to just whip off the road and on to the salt flats and drive around (When its dry of course) or do you have to go to an entrance of a sort. I was not able to find much info on this besides you can drive on the salt flats freely.

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be any specific entry into the flats to drive but most tourist sites like [Utah.com](http://utah.com) talk about using [Bonneville Salt Flats Speedway](http://utah.com/bonneville-salt-flats) as a base for your speed driving.  And given some other information the forums like [Bogley](http://www.bogley.com/forum/showthread.php?24978-SaltFlats-I-ve-looked-everywhere-but-I-can-t-find-an-answer) you might want to do a lot of research before you head out into the great unknown.

Comment: I belive you may enter by the Speedway somewhere, If I find out I shall Post it